# Is there a way to get a volume unmounted when I call CloudFormation delete-stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using CloudFormation to create my environment.  Part of the stack includes creating a volume from a snapshot, associating it with an EC2 instance, and then mounting it.

```
"Resources" : {
    "EBSData" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Volume",
     ...snip...
    },

    "MountPoint" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
     ...snip...
    },

    "myTestInstance" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
     ...snip...
    }
 },
```

When I try to call delete-stack, it fails because the volume is still mounted:

```
  "StackStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to delete: [EBSData, MountPoint].", 
  "CreationTime": "2013-12-03T13:40:58.646Z", 
  "StackName": "myTestStack", 
  "StackStatus": "DELETE_FAILED", 
  "DisableRollback": false
```

Calling delete-stack a 2nd time succeeds, because the instance has been destroyed already.

Are there any hooks into the running instance that get invoked by cloudformation delete-stack where I could un-mount the volume?  Any other way to do this?

Comment: I practically have the same exact problem. I am creating new volumes that I mount at creation of the EC2 instance, but when I delete, the delete flow tries to delete the volumes before it tries to delete the instance. The volumes fail to delete but the instance succeeds. The overall status fails unless delete is called a second time because the instance is already gone.

Answer (score 6):

To get this working, I had to change the way I attached the volume. Instead of using a `AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment`, you can specify EBS volumes to attach to an instance within the properties of that instance:

```
"Resources" : {
    "EBSData" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Volume",
     ...snip...
    },

    "myTestInstance" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "Volumes": [ { "VolumeId": { "Ref": "EBSData" }, "Device": "<device mount point>" }]
        ...snip...
        },
     ...snip...
    }
 },
```

Attaching the volume this way appears to make CloudFormation delete the instance and volume in the correct order. That is, the instance is shut down before the volume is deleted.

Be sure that `EBSData` does not use any references to `myTestInstance` or you'll get a circular dependency.

Comment: There isn't much documentation about this, but your answer seems to be the current best practice, and indeed solves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: herebedragons: the Volume you create needs to be in the same Availability Zone as the EC2 Instance, however this can't be known beforehand, so you would add a `Fn:GetAtt: [myTestInstance, AvailabilityZone]` to the Volume, but this of course introduces the circular dependency we need to avoid

Comment: @lsh I am running onto the same circular dependency issue from getting the AvailabilityZone from the Instance. Did you find any work around?

Comment: you need to use a `AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment` that associates the ec2 instance to the volume and specify the availability zone there. gist here: https://gist.github.com/lsh-0/a6304893e7f97c9f7ac4

Comment: eck sorry, that made little sense. hopefully the gist clears things up.

Comment: This answer worked for me! The only issue is it automatically mounted the entire volume data on my instance home!! Is there a way to tell to mount the data in a different location?                 "Volumes": [ { "VolumeId": { "Ref": "EC2VolumeFromSnapshot" },
                "Device": "/dev/sdh" }],

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my problem [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) with the "DependsOn" resource attribute.

Essentially, this was able to solve my problem (described in a comment to your question):

```
"Resources" : {
    "EBSData" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Volume",
        "DependsOn": "myTestInstance",
     ...snip...
    },
    "MountPoint" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
     ...snip...
    },

    "myTestInstance" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
     ...snip...
    }
 },
```

Note the addition of `"DependsOn": "myTestInstance"` in the Volume resource. Since the VolumeAttachment resource has a built in "DependsOn" for the Volume, all should be good.

**Additional Note:** This hasn't been tested, but will update once it's tested.

Comment: I believe this was a bug that was introduced when cloud formation went parallel.  Originally, a lot of this stuff was sequential, and making it parallel introduced a race condition.  It went away for us a few months ago, before it got painful, so we never really tested it thoroughly enough for me to go beyond "I believe" to "it is".

Comment: Has anyone successfully tested a solution? I'm having the exact same issue, tried DependsOn as above, but stack delete still fails.

Answer (score 1):

What CloudFormation does not do, it cannot undo: your volume is mounted by you (with CloudInit via UserData or else), and CloudFormation has not idea on how to undo this. Thus the stack deletion is stopped because the device stays mouted, and the volume is in "Busy state".

The [recommended way](http://fr.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/aws-cloudformation-under-the-hood-dmg303-aws-reinvent-2013-28437139) is to use CloudFormation CustomRessource to declare the mount point:

```
"ExampleVolumeMount" : {
    "Type" : "Custom::VolumeMount",
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "DependsOn" : ["VolumeAttachment", "ExampleWaitCondition"],
    "Properties" : {
        "ServiceToken" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["CustomResourcePipeline", "Outputs.CustomResourceTopicARN"] },
        "Device" : "/dev/xvdh",
        "MountPoint" : "/mnt/disk",
        "FsType" : "ext3",
        "Format" : "true"
    }
},
```

It uses a ServiceToken created by a sub template: https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/cr-backend-substack-template.template which contain a SQS queue and a SNS topic.

You can check the complete example and scripts on [AWSlabs github account](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-custom-resource-examples/blob/master/examples/mount/).